# Is It Fair to Simplify Gradient Descent as Derivative of Loss Function * Derivative of Activation Function * Derivative of Neuron?

Tags: gradient-descent, backpropagation

Recently I've been trying to think of an easier way to wrap my head around gradient descent rather than just manually derive loss function with respect to weights (and chain and yada yada yada). I was wondering if to make it easier, I could think of it in a simplified way. Mainly, taking advantage of the pieces that make up the chaining. So, the derivative of the loss function * the derivative of the activation function * derivative of activation input (which works to be weight times input so just turns into input).

Is this valid? I feel like something is certainly off about thinking about it in this way. If I could, though, it'd be really nice to just take pre-derived activation functions and loss functions to plug into it.

Does it fall apart at individual layer costs? What's a simple way to deconstruct backpropagation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you spell out your thought mathematically, in formula?